# Pull entire excel row using LinqToExcel

Tags: c#, linq-to-excel

I am trying to pull an entire row of values off of an excel file using linq to excel.  I have all of the column names (there's 104 different ones) and now I just need to get the one row of values associated with each header. What I would like to do is just pull the entire second row of values, but I haven't been able to figure a work around for that.

Does anyone know of a way to just pull one row?  Or do I need to approach this differently and pull the individual value by the header name.

Thank you.

Comment: You would like to pull only the first row after the header? If you have an object `Company` that has 104 properties mapping to the headers, you should be able to do something like `var firstCompany = excel.Worksheet<Company>().First();`.

Comment: @Alden Yes I just wanted to pull the first row after the header.  I avoided making the object since I did not want to hard code out 104 different vals; but my understanding of mapping may be wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the LinqToExcel.Row class ([Documentation](https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel#using-the-linqtoexcelrow-class))

```
var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory("excelFileName");
var firstRow = excel.Worksheet().First();
var companyName = firstRow["CompanyName"];
```

Comment: From the man himself!  Thanks, Paul!  I'm a bit new so the First() never crossed my mind.  Your documentation is very helpful!